# In polars what is the best way to do a rolling mean average grouped by other columns and specify a minimum period?

Tags: python-polars

Let's say I have a dataset similar to this one except we have a Price for each hour of the day each day:

|  | Group | Time | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Group1 | 2021-01-03 00:00:00 | 15.6328 |
| 1 | Group1 | 2021-01-03 05:00:00 | 17.1562 |
| 2 | Group1 | 2021-01-03 08:00:00 | 13.9062 |
| 8 | Group2 | 2021-01-03 10:00:00 | 18.5625 |
| 9 | Group2 | 2021-01-03 00:00:00 | 28.375 |
| 10 | Group2 | 2021-01-03 13:00:00 | 15.4219 |

In polars in python, how could I do the rolling mean of Price per Group per Hour for the last 30 days.  For example for Group1 for Hour 0, I would take the past 30 rows of Group=Group1 and Hour=0 and then do a mean of that.

I implemented the following with groupby_rolling but I can`t specify a min_period in groupby_rolling:

```
df = df.groupby_rolling('Time', by=['Group', 'Hour'], period='30d').agg(
    pl.col('Price').mean().last().alias('PriceAvg')
)
```

Then there's the method rolling_mean which allows to specify a min_period, but using it inside groupby_rolling is much slower.

What is the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do it with a window (`over`) function and the `rolling_mean`.

Below is an example.
I slightly changed your example to a ensure I was able to test the formula.

```
import polars as pl
from datetime import datetime

df = pl.DataFrame({
    'Group' : ['group1', 'group1', 'group1', 
            'group1', 'group1', 'group2'],
    'Time' : [datetime(2021,1,3,0),datetime(2021,1,2,0),datetime(2020,12,20,0),
            datetime(2020,6,1,0),datetime(2021,1,3,5),datetime(2021,1,1,0)],
    'Price' : [1,2,3,4,5,6]
}).with_row_count()

shape: (6, 4)
┌────────┬────────┬─────────────────────┬───────┐
│ row_nr ┆ Group  ┆ Time                ┆ Price │
│ ---    ┆ ---    ┆ ---                 ┆ ---   │
│ u32    ┆ str    ┆ datetime[μs]        ┆ i64   │
╞════════╪════════╪═════════════════════╪═══════╡
│ 0      ┆ group1 ┆ 2021-01-03 00:00:00 ┆ 1     │
│ 1      ┆ group1 ┆ 2021-01-02 00:00:00 ┆ 2     │
│ 2      ┆ group1 ┆ 2020-12-20 00:00:00 ┆ 3     │
│ 3      ┆ group1 ┆ 2020-06-01 00:00:00 ┆ 4     │
│ 4      ┆ group1 ┆ 2021-01-03 05:00:00 ┆ 5     │
│ 5      ┆ group2 ┆ 2021-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 6     │
└────────┴────────┴─────────────────────┴───────┘

# here is the code :
(
    df.sort('Group','Time').with_columns(
        avg_price_same_hour_30_days = 
            pl.col('Price')
            .rolling_mean(window_size = '30d', by='Time', closed='both')
            .over('Group', pl.col('Time').dt.hour()))
    .sort('row_nr')
)

# you can skip the last sort, 
# I included it to make it easy to read the results

shape: (6, 5)
┌────────┬────────┬─────────────────────┬───────┬─────────────────────────────┐
│ row_nr ┆ Group  ┆ Time                ┆ Price ┆ avg_price_same_hour_30_days │
│ ---    ┆ ---    ┆ ---                 ┆ ---   ┆ ---                         │
│ u32    ┆ str    ┆ datetime[μs]        ┆ i64   ┆ f64                         │
╞════════╪════════╪═════════════════════╪═══════╪═════════════════════════════╡
│ 0      ┆ group1 ┆ 2021-01-03 00:00:00 ┆ 1     ┆ 2.0                         │
│ 1      ┆ group1 ┆ 2021-01-02 00:00:00 ┆ 2     ┆ 2.5                         │
│ 2      ┆ group1 ┆ 2020-12-20 00:00:00 ┆ 3     ┆ 3.0                         │
│ 3      ┆ group1 ┆ 2020-06-01 00:00:00 ┆ 4     ┆ 4.0                         │
│ 4      ┆ group1 ┆ 2021-01-03 05:00:00 ┆ 5     ┆ 5.0                         │
│ 5      ┆ group2 ┆ 2021-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 6     ┆ 6.0                         │
└────────┴────────┴─────────────────────┴───────┴─────────────────────────────┘
```

A review of a couple of results:

- For row 0, the 30 days period is from 2020-12-04 to 2021-01-03, and only for the same hour and the same group. That means the rows to be included are row 0, row 1 and row 2. The price result is (1 + 2 + 3) / 3 = 2
- For row 1, the 30 days period is from 2020-12-03 to 2021-01-02, and only for the same hour and the same group. That means the rows to be included are row 1 and row 2. The price result is (2 + 3) / 2 = 2.5

For the remaining rows, only the current row is included